Why vectors multiplication is their dot-product
I have an expression:
$$|\vec{v} - \vec{w}|^2$$
I know I can simply substract the vector $\vec{v}$ from the vector $\vec{w}$ and then calculate resultant vector magnitude, but I want to do that by expanding:
$$|\vec{v} - \vec{w}|^2 =|\vec{v} - \vec{w}|⋅|\vec{v} - \vec{w}|$$
hence I get the following expression:
$$|\vec{v} - \vec{w}|⋅|\vec{v} - \vec{w}|= \vec{v} ⋅ \vec{v} - 2 (\vec{v} ⋅ \vec{w}) + \vec{w}⋅\vec{w}$$
And here's a problem: What does vector multiplication stand for in this context? How can I proof that it stands for the dot-product?
Clarification:
If you have an expression like:
$$|a - b|⋅|a - b|= a ⋅ a - 2 (a ⋅ b) + b⋅b$$
where $a$ and $b$ are numbers then
It's obvious that $a ⋅ a$ stands for multiplication, but I don't understand why does dot-product are to replace this operation in the context of vectors?

Every norm comes with an inner product that's defined using the Polarization Identity. It doesn't have to be the dot product though.

@CyclotomicField This is not true. If the norm is induced by an inner product, you can recover the inner product through the polarisation identity. But that does not have to be the case.

In "$|\vec{v} - \vec{w}||\vec{v} - \vec{w}|= \vec{v} * \vec{v} - 2 (\vec{v} * \vec{w}) + \vec{v}\vec{v}$", you shouldn't use the same symbol $*$ on the LHS (product of two numbers) and the RHS (inner product of two vectors).

To the close-voters: it would be a good idea to give some feedback for this first-time user why, according to you, this question does not meet the guidelines. I see a clear mathematics question, asking how norms and inner products are related.

When you wish to expand the product
$$
||\vec{v} - \vec{w} ||\, ||\vec{v}-\vec{w}|| 
$$
you need to know what the $||.||$ really mean (and I purposefully used $||$ instead of $|$, to avoid confusion with the absolute sign defined for numbers). This is called a norm and defines a sense of distance in your vector space. Not all norms admit further expansion, but you are secretly thinking of a very specific one: the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is defined through
$$
||v||^2 = v\cdot v, 
$$
i.e. the norm derives from the inner product on the vector space. This is a very general occurrence in the theory of vector spaces, in which you can choose to equip the space with

Just a topology
A norm (which then induces a topology)
An inner product (which then induces a norm and a topology).

In your case, you want to use the Euclidean norm. Although you could choose to explicitly not introduce an inner product, if you do want to do that (and since you want to expand your expression you do) the only possibility is the Euclidean inner product, defined through
$$
v\cdot w = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i w_i. 
$$
Not only is it easy to check that this inner product induces the Euclidean norm, the polarisation identity already mentioned in the comments above allows you to check that this is in fact the only such inner product.
If you had chosen a norm that does not derive from an inner product, say the Taxi-cab norm, there is no sensible way to expand your expression.

Thank you, your answer helped me to understand the difference between spaces and now I'm sure that I need to work with the Euclidean one.
However, now I would like to understand if I want to expand the expression as described in my question, and get $\vec{v} ⋅ \vec{v}$, how do I proof that ⋅ stands for this opeartion in Euclidean space: $$\vec{v} ⋅ \vec{w} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_{i} w_{i}$$

Well, that is the definition of the inner (or dot) product on a Euclidean space. Nevertheless, the context in which you want to use this should make it clear what it is you need.

Here's a problem
$$|\vec{v} - \vec{w}|⋅|\vec{v} - \vec{w}|= \vec{v} ⋅ \vec{v} - 2 (\vec{v} ⋅ \vec{w}) + \vec{w}⋅\vec{w}$$
from this context I clearly understand the first expression: $||\vec{v} − \vec{w} ||⋅||\vec{v} −\vec{w} ||$, I can simply calculate the $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ difference hence obtaining a new vector and then a magnitude, however when I use the binomal expansion (BE) it's not that clear what should happen on the Euclidean space, it confuses me because it's not the same as expanding $(a+b)^2$
, but it's $||\vec{a}+\vec{b} ||^2$ and applying the BE formula feels different

I am not sure I see your problem, but you should definitely think about how you are hoping to compute the magnitude of the difference vectors. The definition you use to do that will tell you how it relates to the right-hand side.

I tried computing the magnitude of the difference vectors (on 2D space):
$$||\vec{v} - \vec{w}|| = \sqrt{(v_x - w_x)^2 + (v_y - w_y)^2}$$
thus $$||\vec{v} - \vec{w}||⋅||\vec{v} - \vec{w}|| = (v_x - w_x)^2 + (v_y - w_y)^2$$ and honestly I don't really know how I can relate (proof equality) of that to this:
$$\vec{v} ⋅ \vec{v} - 2 (\vec{v} ⋅ \vec{w}) + \vec{w}⋅\vec{w}$$ and I guess the core reason of my misunderstanding is because I can't proof to myself how ⋅ acts. I agree that they are equal but I can't find the logical explanation how they relate and ⋅ still looks "undefined" for me

I would advise you to read an introduction to inner product spaces to understand the various connections between these different things, but in the meantime I have tried to extend my answer.

Thank you, using your idea I was able to proof that:
$(v_x−w_x)^2+(v_y−v_y)^2=(v_x+v_y)−2(v_xw_x+v_yw_y)+(w_x+w_y)$
Returning to the part where I expanded the expression
$$|\vec{v} −\vec{w} |⋅|\vec{v} −\vec{w} |=\vec{v} −2(\vec{v} ⋅ \vec{w})+\vec{w} ⋅ \vec{w} $$
and it means that $$\vec{v} ⋅ \vec{w} =v_xw_x+v_yw_y$$
Now I can clearly see and prove what the |⋅| function stands for. Again, thank you for your ideas and recommendations. Your help was invaluable. Best regards!
